# Wrapper class rerender issue

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

I am displaying a wrapper list in lightning component.
The wrapper list is populated with values from apex class.
When i am removing a value from the list is showing a null value.
The list size is not decreasing and maintains at maximum size.

---

> **This code works before summer 15 release**

---

```
<aura:attribute name="inventoryWrapperList" type="inventoryAndBookingValue[]"/>   
<aura:iteration items="{!v.iWrapperList}" var="iWrapperForVar"> 

    {!iWrapperForVar.inventoryRecord.NV__Position__c}

</aura:iteration>
```

---

```
public class inventoryAndBookingValue {

    @AuraEnabled
    public DINV__Inventory__c inventoryRecord { get;set; }

    @AuraEnabled
    public Decimal bookingValue { get;set; }

    @AuraEnabled
    public String status { get;set; }

    public inventoryAndBookingValue(NV__Inventory__c inventoryRecord , Decimal bookingValue , String status){

        this.inventoryRecord = inventoryRecord;
        this.bookingValue = bookingValue;
        this.status = status;
    }

}
```

---

```
@AuraEnabled
    public static list<inventoryAndBookingValue> selectedInventory(String productId , String filterDate){


        // Impletemed in Wrapper class named "inventoryAndBookingValue"

        list<DINV__Inventory__c> filteredInventoryList = new list<DINV__Inventory__c>();

        Date filterDateValue = Date.valueOf(filterDate);

        filteredInventoryList = [select id , name , DINV__Remaining_Number_Of_Slots__c , DINV__Position__c , 
                                    DINV__Product__r.Name
                                    from DINV__Inventory__c 
                                    where DINV__Product__c =: productId AND  
                                          DINV__Date__c =: filterDateValue AND
                                          DINV__Remaining_Number_Of_Slots__c > 0];

        list<inventoryAndBookingValue> inventoryBookingWrapperList= new list<inventoryAndBookingValue>();

        for( DINV__Inventory__c inventoryForVar : filteredInventoryList){
            inventoryAndBookingValue tempBookinVar = new inventoryAndBookingValue(inventoryForVar , 0,'None');
            inventoryBookingWrapperList.add(tempBookinVar);
        }

        return inventoryBookingWrapperList;
    }
```

Comment: maybe show some code?

Answer (score 2):

`<aura:attribute name="inventoryWrapperList" type="***[add your upper class].***inventoryAndBookingValue[]"/>`

this will work. You need to mention your top class in the type.

Comment: <aura:attribute name="inventoryWrapperList" type="***[add your upper class].***inventoryAndBookingValue[]"/>  this will work. we need to mention our top class in the type

Comment: I am facing same issue and I tried above steps but not resolved, can anyone help me.